# Configuration Builder - search through subfolders for JSON files

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to know how to set a ConfigurationBuilder to search through all subfolders for JSON files not only in Base Path itself.

```
        var testDataBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        var basePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "myData");
        testDataBuilder.SetBasePath(basePath);

        testDataBuilder.AddJsonFile("myData.json");
        testDataBuilder.AddJsonFile("myDataInSubCatalogue.json"); //HOW TO REACH THAT?

        return testDataBuilder.Build();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why store configuration files in multiple subfolders? In any case, `AddJsonFile` simply accepts a path. You can easily enumerate all `*.json` files in the current folder and call `AddJsonFile`, eg `foreach(var path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(".","*.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories)){ builder.AddJsonFile(path);}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you know the names and locations of the files it's far safer to add them explicitly. Adding arbitrary configuration files without some way of checking their validity is a great way to get hacked.

`AddJsonFile` accepts a path but doesn't care where it points. There's no restriction that forces it to look into the current folder. That path could be a relative or absolute path. It could point to a remote shared folder too, allowing multiple clients to use a centralized configuration file.

You could enumerate all `*.json` files under the current folder and add them one after the other, eg :

```
var jsonFiles=Directory.EnumerateFiles(".","*.json", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(var path in jsonFiles)
{ 
    builder.AddJsonFile(path);
}
```